# I got this error in magento1.9?How to resolve it?

Tags: magento-1.9

**Class 'Mage_Adminhtml_Helper_Data'** not found in

> C:\xampp\htdocs\abc\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Admin.php

**on line 123**

Comment: That means, one of your module is missing helper file. Look here https://magento.stackexchange.com/search?q=helper+data+not+found

Comment: I create Adminhtml directory in core file, then in data.php i added your code after that i got this error.

Comment: Class 'Mage_Adminhtml_Helper_Help_Mapping' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\abc\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Helper\Data.php on line 34

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `Mage_Adminhtml_Helper_Data` is a core class in Magento which you can find at the location `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Data.php`.

Check whether this file does exist in your Magento instance and make sure the class name is exactly as mentioned above. If it is not there, then it simply means you lost some of the core files from your Magento instance.

You can remove this error by replacing the **[file which you can find here](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Data.php)**. But make sure there is no other core files missing in your Magento instance.

Comment: yes i lost helper data.there is no data.php file in that path you mentioned.